# コマンドプロンプトでJDKが使えない

Tags: java, コマンドプロンプト

JDKをインストールし、Pathに通したつもりなのですが、

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.15063]
(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>javac -version
'javac' は、内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド、
操作可能なプログラムまたはバッチ ファイルとして認識されていません。
```

Pathと表示してみても、

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>path
PATH=";C:\ Program Files\java\jdk-9.0.1\";;C:\ Program Files\java\jdk-9.0.1\

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

と表示されてしまいます。
原因として考えられるのを調べたところ、

1. システムの環境変数でPathが通っているか確認
2. 確認時に`；`を忘れていないか
3. 確認時に、`；`は入れずに、`bin`と入力するのを忘れていないか
4. ユーザー環境変数のPathに入力
5. `Path-HOME`の環境変数に入力する

とやってみましたができません。`java -version` は通るのですが、`javac -version`が通りません。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 3):

javac.exe は、デフォルトでは C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1\bin フォルダの中にインストールされます。したがって、環境変数PATHには、C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1ではなく、C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1\bin を設定する必要があります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。助かりました。根本的な仕組みについて深く理解が必要だと痛感です。頑張ります。

Answer (score 0):

結果、
JAVA_HOME を新規で”インストール先”と入力
その後に
pathに”インストール先bin”と入力したら通りました。バックスラッシュや；に関しては私の場合は必要なかったです。